# Hashing a password

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have built a login form but not a sign up form so i am putting the users details directly into the sql database.
I have found out that cakephp automatically hashes the password when the user tries to login, but at the moment I cant login because the password in the database is not hashed.
how does cakephp hash the passwords?

My security salt is `Dhhfei38fhDg37dg6Dg208Dh3h380Hrjd3`

Could you please walk me through what it does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashed passwords in cakephp are created by:

```
$hashedPasswords = Security::hash($yourPass, NULL, true);
```

[Check the cakephp manual for more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en)

Comment: I recommend using a behavior to keep the code DRY: dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp

Answer (score 4):

```
debug(AuthComponent::password("your-password"));
```

That's if you are hashing your password this way inside your UserModel.

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Answer (score 2):

Add a new user with a password.  You can take the hash value of the new user's password and paste it into other user's records.

Comment: I havn't created the signup form yet though, was just wondering if anyone knew how cake does it soi can leave the signup form till later but still be able to login in. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of Cakephp 2.0, Cake only hashes passwords in the login process,
on other places (like register-method...), the password won't be hashed automatically, that's because it was considered a strange behaviour to people who where new to cakephp.
If you want to hash the password, you need to use the method Sudhir mentioned.
One of the advantages that cake does not hash passwords automatically anymore is, that you can more easily check the password complexity ( if there are included special characters, numbers, letters ecc).

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to – password hashing in cakephp](http://techpub.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/how-to-password-hashing-in-cakephp/): *"Security::hash takes the type sha1."*